# Is there a property relating gcd(a, b) % c and gcd(a %c, b%c) % c. Here all a,b,c are natural numbers i.e.>0 and '%' represents modulo operator.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm, big-numbers

I have been facing some difficulty solving problems relating the gcd and modulo operator.
If I use the Euclidean algorithm then it works fine when either a or b is small because in one step itself a is reduced to b and b is reduced to a%b.
Here the operator '%' represents modulo operator which gives the remainder r when a is divided by b.
For example:
Euclidean Algorithm: gcd(a, b) = gcd(b, a%b)
gcd(10000000000, 528) = gcd(528, 496)...... (10000000000%528 = 496)
But my problem is that if a is too big and then b is also of the same order then it becomes impossible to write an algorithm in a language like C++ due to integer overflow. Besides why should I bother calculating first a then b and then take the mod of their gcd when I can (if possible) apply some property since I want only the gcd modulo c and not the exact number.
I know I should have asked this on stackoverflow but the properties that I want to know regarding mod and gcd are more related to math.

Long story short, is there a way to find gcd(a, b) % c without having to calculate a or b if a or b are really large expressions. Like a = 100 * 100 * 100 * ...... 10 times or maybe more. Or if I don't know the exact number as they can change and I have to calculate it for different cases.

edit:
Here c is an integer where c < 10000000
a= pow(A, n) + pow(B, n) where A, B, n are all >100000

Comment: It sounds like you should be more specific on what exactly $a$, $b$, and $c$ are supposed to be.

Comment: Can you give any more explanation as to why you're interested in the GCD modulo $c$? This seems like a kind of weird thing to try and calculate. Perhaps if you explain it could shed some light on how to proceed.

Comment: I was trying to mainly solve this question.

https://www.codechef.com/AUG18B/problems/GCDMOD

Comment: OK, let's assume $A \ge B$. Can you reduce $A^N + B^N$ modulo $A - B$ by hand?

Comment: How can I reduce it by hand? The term A - B is too big.

Comment: I kind of meant can you use any facts about modular arithmetic. Have you done much modular arithmetic before? You can use here that if $x \equiv y \pmod n$ then for any $k$, $x^k \equiv y^k \pmod n$.

Comment: I completely agree with this. I know this property. I have some basic experience with modulo arithmetic. But I am unsure whether this will hold in gcd also and if not, is there some other simplification?

I want to ask if c = 500, let's say. Then also would we require to calculate both the terms? Can we not apply some modulo arithmetic to simplify it a little?
Thank you for your prompt response.

Comment: I'm exactly suggesting that you apply some modular arithmetic to simplify it a little. We have that $B \equiv A \pmod{A - B}$, so $A^N + B^N \equiv 2 \cdot A^N \pmod{A - B}$. Then to reduce $A^N + B^N$ modulo $A - B$, you just need to reduce $2 \cdot A^N$ modulo $A - B$. Congruence classes multiply, so use modular exponentiation by squaring to calculate $A^N$, and multiply by $2$, and reduce again. Proceed by Euclid's algorithm.

Comment: But is the gcd(a, b) mod c equal to gcd(a mod c, b mod c) mod c? I can apply the binary exponentiation to reduce time complexity to log n but will the gcd thing hold or break.

Comment: No, that's not generally the case. Take $a = 5$, $b = 10$, $c = 3$. My suggestion gives you time complexity of $\log N + \log(A - B)$, which should do fairly well.

Comment: Thankyou very much.